# How to create a TCL opaque TEAPOT

Tags: tcl

I am trying to figure out how to create an opaque local TCL TEAPOT repository. I have Googled and Googled and it seems I am looking for the wrong thing as I have not been able to find a good document on how to do what I want to do.

What I am trying to do is to setup a local Teapot that I can point to and wrap/compile my application (for Windows or for Linux). This will also give me a tighter control on the packages and versions that are used on a particular version of the application.

From what I have read, an Opaque Teapot repository is not associated with a TCL shell installation. Therefore you can store packages from other platforms on it. The regular Teapot (associated with a TCL shell, only allows packages that are compatible with the TCL shell architecture). In other words, I can not add Linux packages into a Windows Teapot.

Below is what I know and have done so far.

1) To create a opaque (not associated with a TCL Shell)  repository

```
  teacup-admin create {.\my_teapot}
```

2) To get a package from the ActiveState repository (for example)

```
  teacup get base-tk-thread 8.6.1.1.297611 linux-glibc2.3-x86_64
```

3) To add a file to the opaque repository

```
  teapot-admin add ./my_teapot ./application-base-tk-thread-8.6.1.1.297611-linux-glibc2.3-x86_64
```

The three steps above work fine.

The problem I hit was trying to figure out how to add my own packages or packages from the ActiveState Teapot.

The "teapot-admin add" command above it seems that only adds files. Therefore I am not sure how the repository will figure out all the files that belong to a single package and how it will avoid collisions on file names.

Any pointers to a step by step documentation on how to do this or anything that can help me with this would be greately appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to summarize and add a few more details of what I learned:

Following Andy's recommendations I used the commands below to create, add, remove and list the contents of my platform independent (opaque) Teapot.

set opaque_repo ./my_teapot_linux
teacup-admin create $opaque_repo
teapot-admin add -v $opaque_repo $file
teapot-admin remove $opaque_repo $file $version
teapot-admin list $opaque_repo

To get a list of the packages available for all the platforms in the ActiveState Teapot
teacup list --all-platforms

Then you can do the command below to get the specific package, version and platform that you want:
teacup get $package $version $platform

Then finally I used the command below to add the package to the opaque Teapot
teapot-admin add -v $opaque_repo $file

As Andy mentioned you can create your own packages and it will generate a .tm file and you can add this file to the opaque Teapot using the "teapot-admin add" command. Note that this command supports different file formats including Zip files. Check the documentation for more details.

Regards,
Frank

Answer (score 0):

To add a package to your own teapot, you will need to create a package file. Since you clearly are using the Active State tools, use the package editor to create your package. The package editor will then create a "package-xxxxx.tm" file. That file can then be added to your teapot via`teapot-admin add` command. The included documentation for the package editor will show you how to create a package file.

Comment: Thanks for the info Andy. I am generating the "package-xxxxx.tm" files so it should be simple. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Hi Andy, I tried your recommendation and I can add the "package-xxxxx.tm". I was trying to add the other packages from the ActiveState repository when I realized the tm files from ActiveState do not have the actual code. How can I add specific packages from ActiveState? For example Img 1.4.0.4. Currently I am doing: teacup get Img 1.4.0.4
teapot-admin add '.\my_teapot' package-Img-1.4.0.4-tcl.tm    I would also like to add the package required by those packages.

Comment: From what I gather you are getting copies of packages from the Active State repository and then trying to add them to your local repository? I hope that doesn't violate the Active State license and I'm not sure why you would want to do it (you know you use multiple repositories?). But tracking the dependencies between packages will be your problem to solve.

Comment: Hi Andy, The packages are typically installed from ActiveState repository into the TCL installation. The problem is that the TCL installation is platform dependent and does not allow the user to add packages to it that are from another platform. What I am trying to do is to create my own linux based teapot under Windows so I can wrap my application for linux. Currently the ActiveState tool that i am using is taking the latest version of the open source package and that is what is causing my version conflict. With a local repository I can control the version the wrap app will use.

Comment: The "teacup" on the local installation is indeed platform specific as it makes little sense otherwise. However, a "teapot" being served from some arbitrary machine will hold packages of any architecture. You can use the "teacup archive" command to add teapot archives to a local installation. In this way your packages can be picked up from your "teapot" and you can deal with the Active State one normally. This is what I do for my local packages and it works well. Otherwise it seems to me that you buy a large maintenance burden to try and track Active State.